# Remap "Caps Lock" to tilde ~

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, osx-mavericks

Reaching for the ~ on the upper left with my pinkie is becoming a pain. Is it possible to remap this to the "Caps Lock" key in one go? I tried KeyRemap4MacBook and PCKeyboardHack but failed.

PCKeyboardHack can remap the "Caps Lock" to key to (`), but I still have to do SHIFT + CAPS LOCK to achieve my ~. What I am after for is when I press "CAPS LOCK", it should be ~.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [PCKeyboardHack](https://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/pckeyboardhack.html.en) to map caps lock to a key like F19:

[image]

Then map F19 to shift+` in [private.xml](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/xml.html.en):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <item>
    <name>test</name>
    <identifier>test</identifier>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::F19, KeyCode::BACKQUOTE, ModifierFlag::SHIFT_L</autogen>
  </item>
</root>
```